# Fill dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

im trying to fill a dropdownlist and it gives me only one value. How can i put all the values given from the database?

```
var con = new SqlConnection("server=(local);Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True");

try
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("GetDates", con);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Dates", SqlDbType.DateTime, 50, ParameterDirection.Output, false, 0, 50, "Dates", DataRowVersion.Default, null));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Hours", SqlDbType.NChar, 10, ParameterDirection.Output, false, 0, 50, "Hours", DataRowVersion.Default, null));
    command.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.OutputParameters;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    DateTime Dates = (DateTime)command.Parameters["@Dates"].Value;
    string Hours = (string)command.Parameters["@Hours"].Value;


    day.Items.Add(Hours);



}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    con.Close();
}
```

And this is the SP

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetDates (@Dates datetime OUTPUT, @Hours NCHAR(10) OUTPUT) 
AS
    SELECT @Dates = Dates, @Hours = Hours from test..Dates where taken = 0
GO
```

Comment: Why ExecuteNonQuery? Use ExecuteReader or any other way te get result set then use LINQ to put it into DDL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change the `GetDates` stored procedure to return `Dates, Hours` like below

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetDates () 

    AS
        SELECT Dates, Hours from test..Dates where taken = 0
    GO
```

and then

```
con.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("GetDates", con);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
day.DataSource = dt;
day.DataTextField = "Hours";
day.DataValueField = "Dates";
day.DataBind();
```

Comment: I edit and put the SP i use with 2 outputs values. When i do your solution it not fill de dropdownlist, any idea?

Comment: @user2631328 no need of outputs values, use select statement

Answer (score 0):

```
        DataSet DropDownListValues = urclassname.GetDates();

        DataRow dr;

        DropDownList1.Items.Clear();

        DropDownList1.Items.Add("");

        if (DropDownListValues.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            int k = 0;

            while (k < DropDownListValues.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
            {
                dr = DropDownListValues.Tables[0].Rows[k];

                string Hours = dr["Hours"].ToString().Trim();

                string Dates = dr["Dates"].ToString().Trim();

                DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(Hours , Dates));

                k++;
            }
        }
```